# PDO, no recuerdo como funciona :/

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Yo ya vi esté tema, pero no recuerdo adecuadamente el funcionamiento de la conexión con PDO y quisiera saber si alguien puede ayudarme.

Esté es el código pero no recuerdo muy bien como funciona exactamente

```
class Conexion{
    protected $db;
    private $driver="mysql";
    private $host="localhost";
    private $bd="Conjunto";
    private $usuario="root";
    private $clave="";

    public function __construct(){
        try{
            $db=new PDO("{$this->driver}:host={$this->host};dbname={$this->bd}", $this->usuario, $this->clave);
            $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            return $db;
        }
    
        catch(PDOException $e){
        echo "No se a podido establecer la conexión con la base de datos". $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

}
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias

Comment: ¿Cuál es la duda específica?, ¿este código funciona o da errores?

Comment: en el manual [se explica con ejemplos](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.construct.php#refsect1-pdo.construct-examples)

Comment: El código funciona correctamente, la conexión la cree con un profesor el cual me explico como funcionaba, pero la verdad ya no recuerdo bien el funcionamiento de este. En pocas palabras ando un poco perdido con el tema de conectar con la base de datos

Comment: Checa el enlace que te dieron en el otro comentario, cuando tengas dudas específicas te podemos ayudar con gusto

Comment: Mi duda abarca la parte del constructor, lo que es el try y el catch

Comment: Aquí puedes leer sobre ello https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.exceptions.php

Comment: Ah listo, gracias